# : High CPU Usage By adr_character Command

Tags: nginx, ubuntu, cpu-usage, linode

My linode server is running on UBUNTU 20.4 + nginx.

Recently my cpu usage increased up to 100%. At first I thought PM2 caused the problem. Uninstall PM2 but the problem still exists. Even rebooting did not solve the problem

When I run this command,

```
 ps fax o uid,%cpu,%mem,time,comm | awk '0+$0 == 33 {print}'
```

and it shows as belows

```
   33  0.3 13.3 00:00:08  \_ php-fpm7.4
   33  0.0 10.4 00:00:02  \_ php-fpm7.4
   33  0.1 12.3 00:00:02  \_ php-fpm7.4
   33  0.0  0.5 00:00:01  \_ nginx
   33 96.9 18.6 00:41:26 adr_character
```

it seems the adr_character command takes up to 96.9% of the cpu usage.

I try to kill the process but after a few minutes adr_character comes back, alive.

Can someone tell me what this adr_character is? and how I can solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I got it. When I run the command below,

```
ps aux
```

It give me more info about all the processes running. It helps me to identify the source of the problem. So I'm able to delete the unwanted program dan kill the process.

Hope this can help others ..